# Web Setup Project - 'special folder' for working folder

Tags: installation, project

I'm currently building a web setup project and need to include some executables for the initial installation process. I need to include vsdbcmd + libs for creating an update script when installing my web application. My question is whether or not it is possible to include and extract additional files in the 'working folder' (temp folder) used for the installation? I cannot seem to find that particular 'special folder' under the File System view. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a little followup on my requestion. As a temporary solution I create a working folder in Program Files and delete this when I'm done. I would however have preferred using the temporary working folder.